# Location of Eden in Seder Histalshilus

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism

In Likutei Torah parshas Tzav (pg. 16d and onward) and Shaar HaEmunah by the Mittler Rebbe (ch. 57 and onward) discuss the splitting of the river in the future, and part of that description is that it will reveal the level of "Eden". Is it safe to say that Eden, at least in a general sense, refers to Atzmus? In some places in Chassidus and Kabbalah (don't remember exactly where), Eden is identified with Chochmah I'lai, which I think (correct if wrong) refers not only to Chochmah of Atzilus, but also Chochmah of the worlds higher than Atzlius. But maybe that's very specifically, but generally is Eden basically Atzmus? (Since it says in Shaar HaEmunah pg. 95a that the splitting of the river will cause us to get the inner dimensions of Torah ("from Atzmus Ohr Ayn Sof").

Basically, just explain the level of Eden generally / specifically of where exactly it can be placed in Seder Histalshilus (if at all), and bring sources.

**EDIT** this passage from Shaar HaEmunah ch. 56 may be helpful in the discussion:

> שרש משיח בפנימית ועצמות המאציל שלמעלה משרש התחלקות הקוין שמתחלקים מח"ס כו' וזהו שע"י משיח דוקא יומשך ויושפע לישראל בחי' פנימית התורה שהן טעמי תורה ומצות שהן עתה בבחי' ההעלם גנוז בתורה בלתי נגלה גם בח"ס שרש האצילות כולו כו' והוא הנקרא עדן סתימאה דעין לא ראתה כו' ‏

Comment: Probably not, because Atzmus wouldn't have a name like that. Pnimius Atik?